# Array Length not Changing after delete

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that holds the desk of cards, but after delete, the array length is still the same.

```js
var cards = ["1H", "2H", "3H", "4S", "5C", "6D"];
console.log("Cards Count: " + cards.length); // return 6 
delete cards[3]; // return true 
console.log("Cards Count: " + cards.length); // still returning 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `splice` instead of `delete` for removing items in an array. This is because using `delete` does not change the length of an array.

That is why the length is still the same because the `undefined` item is still counted.

```js
var cards = ["1H", "2H", "3H", "4S", "5C", "6D"];
console.log("Cards Count: " + cards.length); // return 6 
//delete cards[3]; // return true 
cards.splice(3,1);
console.log(cards);
console.log("Cards Count: " + cards.length); // still returning 6
```

Comment: I understand now that `splice(3,1)` completely removes the item. The `3` is the item index, how about the `1`, what does it mean?

Comment: The value `1` is the number of items to be removed.

Comment: This is the reference for the `splice` function https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Comment: "*`delete` will just replace the item with undefined*" not exactly. It will make an empty slot in your array. That won't change the length, but this slot won't get visited by some methods like forEach, map etc. while if it was just set to undefined, these methods would still go in.

Comment: @Kaiido I updated the answer, could you confirm, thanks

Comment: Not exactly... Sorry. You can very well have an Array of length 33 with only empty slots (`Array(33)`). It's not because values are undefined that the length is set. That would go too deep to explain how an Array is represented in memory to be exact though, so maybe you just want to say that "delete doesn't change the length of your array".

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are fixed length. When you declare an array JVM allocates specific size (say 6 in your case) to your array. Even If you delete the values from the array length of the array does not change.

If you want dynamically changing array you can try with ArrayList , which is a collection but it works as a dynamic array.

Comment: Hi! The question was about JavaScript `Array`, while you seem to have confused the question to be about Java `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use splice method to add/remove array items in JavaScript.

ex: 
`array.splice(arrayIndex, No of Element to be removed, "xx", "yy");` for adding
 
`array.splice(arrayIndex, No of Element to be removed);` for removing

```js
var cards = ["1H", "2H", "3H", "4S", "5C", "6D"];
console.log(cards.length); // 6
cards.splice(2, 1); // removes 3rd element of array
console.log(cards); // ["1H", "2H", "4S", "5C", "6D"];
console.log(cards.length); // 5
cards.splice(2, 0, "xx", "yy");
console.log(cards); // ["1H", "2H", "4S", "5C", "6D"];
console.log(cards.length); // 5
```